# /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libOpenCL.so.1: no version information available

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, sycl

When I am running `computecpp_info`

```
$ /usr/local/computecpp/bin/computecpp_info 
/usr/local/computecpp/bin/computecpp_info: /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libOpenCL.so.1: no version information available (required by /usr/local/computecpp/bin/computecpp_info)
/usr/local/computecpp/bin/computecpp_info: /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libOpenCL.so.1: no version information available (required by /usr/local/computecpp/bin/computecpp_info)
********************************************************************************

ComputeCpp Info (CE 0.7.0)

********************************************************************************

Toolchain information:

GLIBC version: 2.19
GLIBCXX: 20150426
This version of libstdc++ is supported.

********************************************************************************


Device Info:

Discovered 3 devices matching:
  platform    : <any>
  device type : <any>

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Device 0:

  Device is supported                     : NO - Device does not support SPIR
  CL_DEVICE_NAME                          : GeForce GTX 750 Ti
  CL_DEVICE_VENDOR                        : NVIDIA Corporation
  CL_DRIVER_VERSION                       : 384.111
  CL_DEVICE_TYPE                          : CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Device 1:

  Device is supported                     : UNTESTED - Device not tested on this OS
  CL_DEVICE_NAME                          : Intel(R) HD Graphics
  CL_DEVICE_VENDOR                        : Intel(R) Corporation
  CL_DRIVER_VERSION                       : r5.0.63503
  CL_DEVICE_TYPE                          : CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Device 2:

  Device is supported                     : YES - Tested internally by Codeplay Software Ltd.
  CL_DEVICE_NAME                          : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
  CL_DEVICE_VENDOR                        : Intel(R) Corporation
  CL_DRIVER_VERSION                       : 1.2.0.475
  CL_DEVICE_TYPE                          : CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU 

If you encounter problems when using any of these OpenCL devices, please consult
this website for known issues:
https://computecpp.codeplay.com/releases/v0.7.0/platform-support-notes

********************************************************************************
```

and when running `clinfo`

```
$ clinfo 
clinfo: /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libOpenCL.so.1: no version information available (required by clinfo)
Number of platforms                               2
  Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
  Platform Vendor                                 NVIDIA Corporation
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 9.0.282
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer
  Platform Extensions function suffix             NV

  Platform Name                                   Intel(R) OpenCL
  Platform Vendor                                 Intel(R) Corporation
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_icd cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_spir
  Platform Extensions function suffix             INTEL

  Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     GeForce GTX 750 Ti
  Device Vendor                                   NVIDIA Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x10de
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 CUDA
  Driver Version                                  384.111
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Topology (NV)                            PCI-E, 01:00.0
  Max compute units                               5
  Max clock frequency                             1110MHz
  NVIDIA Compute Capability                       5.0
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     1
    Supported partition types                     None
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             1024x1024x64
  Max work group size                             1024
  Preferred work group size multiple              32
  Warp size (NV)                                  32
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                 1 / 1       
    short                                                1 / 1       
    int                                                  1 / 1       
    long                                                 1 / 1       
    half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                1 / 1       
    double                                               1 / 1        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  Yes
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              2094530560 (1.951GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           523632640 (499.4MiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              No
  Integrated memory (NV)                          No
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       4096 bits (512 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        81920
  Global Memory cache line                        128 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             32
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            134217728 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Max 2D image size                             16384x16384 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             4096x4096x4096 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 256
    Max number of write image args                16
  Local memory type                               Local
  Local memory size                               49152 (48KiB)
  Registers per block (NV)                        65536
  Max constant buffer size                        65536 (64KiB)
  Max number of constant args                     9
  Max size of kernel argument                     4352 (4.25KiB)
  Queue properties                                
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Profiling timer resolution                      1000ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            No
    Kernel execution timeout (NV)                 Yes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution (NV)       Yes
    Number of async copy engines                  1
  Prefer user sync for interop                    No
  printf() buffer size                            1048576 (1024KiB)
  Built-in kernels                                
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer

  Platform Name                                   Intel(R) OpenCL
Number of devices                                 2
  Device Name                                     Intel(R) HD Graphics
  Device Vendor                                   Intel(R) Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x8086
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 
  Driver Version                                  r5.0.63503
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Max compute units                               20
  Max clock frequency                             1200MHz
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     0
    Supported partition types                     None
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             256x256x256
  Max work group size                             256
  Preferred work group size multiple              32
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                16 / 16      
    short                                                8 / 8       
    int                                                  4 / 4       
    long                                                 1 / 1       
    half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                1 / 1       
    double                                               0 / 0        (n/a)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  Yes
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (n/a)
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              1709598311 (1.592GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           854799155 (815.2MiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              Yes
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       1024 bits (128 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        524288
  Global Memory cache line                        64 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             16
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            53424947 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Max 2D image size                             16384x16384 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             2048x2048x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 128
    Max number of write image args                128
  Local memory type                               Local
  Local memory size                               65536 (64KiB)
  Max constant buffer size                        854799155 (815.2MiB)
  Max number of constant args                     8
  Max size of kernel argument                     1024
  Queue properties                                
    Out-of-order execution                        No
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Profiling timer resolution                      80ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            No
    SPIR versions                                 1.2 
  Prefer user sync for interop                    Yes
  printf() buffer size                            4194304 (4MiB)
  Built-in kernels                                block_motion_estimate_intel;block_advanced_motion_estimate_check_intel;block_advanced_motion_estimate_bidirectional_check_intel
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Device Extensions                               cl_intel_accelerator cl_intel_advanced_motion_estimation cl_intel_driver_diagnostics cl_intel_motion_estimation cl_intel_planar_yuv cl_intel_packed_yuv cl_intel_required_subgroup_size cl_intel_subgroups cl_intel_va_api_media_sharing cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_icd cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_spir 

  Device Name                                     Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
  Device Vendor                                   Intel(R) Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x8086
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 (Build 475)
  Driver Version                                  1.2.0.475
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 
  Device Type                                     CPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Max compute units                               8
  Max clock frequency                             3600MHz
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     8
    Supported partition types                     by counts, equally, by names (Intel)
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             8192x8192x8192
  Max work group size                             8192
  Preferred work group size multiple              128
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                 1 / 32      
    short                                                1 / 16      
    int                                                  1 / 8       
    long                                                 1 / 4       
    half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                1 / 8       
    double                                               1 / 4        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              8260567040 (7.693GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           2065141760 (1.923GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              Yes
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       1024 bits (128 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        262144
  Global Memory cache line                        64 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             480
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            129071360 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Max 2D image size                             16384x16384 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             2048x2048x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 480
    Max number of write image args                480
  Local memory type                               Global
  Local memory size                               32768 (32KiB)
  Max constant buffer size                        131072 (128KiB)
  Max number of constant args                     480
  Max size of kernel argument                     3840 (3.75KiB)
  Queue properties                                
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
    Local thread execution (Intel)                Yes
  Profiling timer resolution                      1ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            Yes
    SPIR versions                                 1.2
  Prefer user sync for interop                    No
  printf() buffer size                            1048576 (1024KiB)
  Built-in kernels                                
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_spir cl_khr_fp64 

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  No platform
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [other]              Success [NV]
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No platform
```

Here, I tried to find the reason of `/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libOpenCL.so.1: no version information available` and tried to fix this issue, but I didn't get any fruitful help. Please help by explaining or referring something to get it clear.

Comment: Your own printout indicates that the NVIDIA GPU is not supported, and [the reference page](https://developer.codeplay.com/computecppce/v0.7.0/supported-platforms) suggested in your printout indicates only support for AMD and Intel platforms.

Comment: hi @RobertCrovella Thanks!!! Does it mean that `computecpp_info` showing two time warning because of `device 0` and `device 1` don't support it, and `clinfo` showing 1 time because of `nvidia cuda`?

Comment: The warning ( and it is a warning) is likely because you are mixing versions or the build system for your application and the system you run on are not the same. It is a harmless warning.

Comment: @talonmies thanks, but I didn't get what exactly you mean.

Comment: This means there is no OpenCL binary for that hardware. ComputeCpp does not work with CUDA, but the compiler can be used to output PTX instructions that are understood by the NVidia hardware. There is some background here https://www.codeplay.com/portal/12-06-17-adding-experimental-ptx-support-to-computecpp-for-nvidia and the compiler flags are documented here https://developer.codeplay.com/computecppce/latest/computecpp-with-ptx